# How to add metadata using Exiftool?

Tags: metadata, exiftool

I have an image, where I want to create a new tag called "DepthMap" and add an image to that tag. I have searched a lot but could not find an example to do it.

Comment: I'm assuming that [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxquestions/comments/hwct84/how_do_i_add_new_metadata_using_exiftool/) is your reddit post.  Here you give the additional info that you want to embed an actual file as the depth map, which narrows the tag down to the `XMP-GDepth` tag group rather than the `XMP-Device:Cameras` group I mention in that post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to embed a depth map image into the `XMP-GDepth:DepthImage` tag, the basic command would be:
`exiftool "-xmp-gdepth:DepthImage<=depthmap.jpg" File.jpg`

But note that there might be other data required.  See [this exiftool forum post](https://exiftool.org/forum/index.php?topic=8587.msg44126#msg44126) for more info.  A couple changes from that post is that the config file is no longer necessary and `xmp-gdepth:data` is now `XMP-GDepth:DepthImage` as shown in the above command.